# Databinding behaving sporadically with bound list executing multiple BackgroundWorkers

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I'm binding an IList to a ListBox. Each item in the list executes a method that runs a backgroundworker operation. This class has a Progress property that is then bound to a DataTemplate of the ListBox. The progress property implements INotifyPropertyChange.

Obviously, the idea relatively simple: run multiple background jobs and report the progress of each job back to the user. I'm also trying to deliver other properties like "JobStepText" or "IsBusy".

I'm using an MVVM pattern. The ViewModel creates the list and kicks off the async jobs.

This works, however I'm running into synchronization issues it seems, because sometimes the work gets done and the on change events never makes it to the UI. It's behaving completely random - sometimes it does here and there and sometimes it doesn't.

I've been googling this for the last few days and am just stumped on how to correct this.

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="ProgressTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Height="20" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding Failed, Converter={StaticResource ProgressConverter}}"></Image>
            <Image Height="20" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" Name="Spinner" Stretch="Uniform" Source="/Aps.SaasHr.M3Migration.Wpf;component/Images/spinner.jpg" Visibility="{Binding Failed, Converter={StaticResource ProgressConverter}}">
                <Image.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Spin360}" />
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Image.Triggers>
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>

            <ProgressBar Grid.Column="1" Height="40" IsEnabled="True"  Value="{Binding Progress, Mode=OneWay}">

            </ProgressBar>

            <Border Grid.Column="1" Padding="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextBlock.Foreground="Black" TextBlock.FontWeight="Black" TextBlock.FontSize="18">
                <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal"  >
                    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Config.ClassType, StringFormat='{}{0}\\'}" ></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Config.Name}" ></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Progress, StringFormat=' (%{0})', Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding CurrentText}" FontSize="12" Padding="3"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Below is what kicks off the worker. During the async operation properties like LogText get set.

```
public void ProcessAsync(Action<RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs> complete)
    {
        _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, e) =>
        {
            IsBusy = false;
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Failed = true;
                AddLogText("An unexpected error occured: " + e.Error.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                Progress = 100;
                Failed = false;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("LogText");
            complete(e);
        };
        IsBusy = true;
        _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

And from the class that is child of the list (the worker class w/ background worker)

```
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    #endregion


    public string LogText
    {
        get { return _logText; }
        set
        {
            _logText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LogText");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm concenerd with your implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged if you're performing a `OnPropertyChanged("LogText");` in your completed.  Can you show more code?

Comment: Sure, I'm fine with the implementation. But if anything regarding INotifyPropertyChanged, how this implementation as a whole reacts with the Dispatcher is what's causing me so much confusion. Gets there sometimes, sometimes doesn't. Obviously a thread synchronization issue, I just don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: What isn't getting notified? Strictly this LogText="Unexpected error" idea and Progress=100? Because BGW's completed will run on the `calling` thread, which I can only assume is the UI here.  Any possibility that another thread invoked the ProcessAsync?  Lastly, thought about `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);` to force it to the UI? Would want null and CheckAccess() checks.

Comment: There are set operations both on the callback shown here and the asyncronous thread. Surprisingly, both are actually having troubles - hence why I suspect threading synchronization issues. Yes, _worker.RunWorkerAsync() is invoked from the UI thread. I'll try implementing the dispatcher on all PropertyChanged operations.

Comment: That solved my problem. Just implementing Dispatcher.Invoke during OnPropertyChanged did the trick. Now I only with I had a better understanding of why calls on a thread separate from the UI thread sometimes get lost.

Comment: I would say that is a hack only that helped us diagnose your UI thread is in fact not the calling thread for your BGW. I suggest looking into Sheridan's answer to get your concept correctly implemented without hacks. Let us know here if its similar enough, or make a new question and we'll see if we can resolve this fully.

Comment: I can't say I agree with that for reasons mentioned below. My question here has not to do with what class is invoking the bw and is irrelevant. I was already aware that my background thread is not the same as my ui thread. That's the question: why does it behave sporadically when invoking onpropertchanged from thread other than the ui. The binding sometimes occurs and sometimes doesn't and the ui thread isn't blocked. Its like some messages get lost. I've had plenty of experience dealing with a sync binding in the past without issue, and would simply like to know what makes this so different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say this, but I think that your current approach sounds horrendous. In my opinion, data type classes should just be holders of data. There shouldn't be any of this kind of functionality in there and especially not multi-threaded functionality... you're just asking for the trouble that you have now got.

Instead of that approach, how about implementing your multi-threaded functionality in the view model and just update the `Progress` (and any other properties) of the collection items as and when your background threads report back, eg. in the usual way? If you do that, you'll find that you'll have far fewer problems.

Comment: I'm not sure that I agree here. Whether the datatype class is the one that kicks off the separate thread or not is irrelevant; the thread still runs on a separate thread either way, and eventually that thread has to set the property on the datatype regardless. I'm using a background worker for multithreading which only implements ReportProgress, thus I'm updating the properties from a thread other than the UI. Your suggestion really is to always update the properties on the UI thread and queue them on the Dispatcher - which is actually the same solution proposed by bland, is it not?